# Springer references do not appear immediately, several compilations are needed

Tags: cross-referencing

i use the following code ( springer template)

the problem that i neeed to repeat compilation several  times, and sometimes i have to put the enitre folder in an other directory.
How can i resove this problem please?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file template.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals.          Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article. Delete % signs as needed.
%
% This template includes a few options for different layouts and
% content for various journals. Please consult a previous issue of
% your journal as needed.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%
% First comes an example EPS file -- just ignore it and
% proceed on the \documentclass line
% your LaTeX will extract the file if required
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
%\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)

%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}   
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

% Reference package
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
% pdf to eps package
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{epsfig}
%% Numbered
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

%% Numbered without titles
%\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}

%% Harvard
%\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% Vancouver numbered
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}

%% Vancouver name/year
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model4-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% APA style
%\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% AMA style
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}
%Interdection of alinea
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%            Begin document        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

% BibTeX users please use one of
%\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations
%\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences
%\bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics
%\bibliographystyle{spr-chicago}      % Chicago style, author-year citations
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
%\bibliography{}   % name your BibTeX data base
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}   % name your BibTeX data base

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is the expected normal behaviour that you have to recompile your document to get the references right: latex + bibtex/biber + latex + latex. Moreover, if you don't cite any references, the bibliography will stay empty. As a test, to see all references, add `\nocite{*}` to the document and do the cycle (latex + bibtex + ...). See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/110998) for details.

Comment: Include the `natbib` package only once, as `\usepackage[numbers,round]{natbib}`.

Comment: I guess the effect of putting *the entire folder into a new directory* is just that you get rid of the auxiliary files that are generated by the repeated runs of latex, and which collect the citation information. To start anew, just delete `*.aux` and `*.bbl`, but this effectively prevents latex from arriving at the final document.

Comment: Even when i delete *.aux and *.bbl, or when i\usepackage[numbers,round]{natbib} , nothing happen

Comment: This problee related problem can be related with the tex maker

Comment: In the past, i used to comile with texnic center; i had to compile only two times to ger references

Comment: unfortunately, when i try to compile the file with Texnic center, or copy and paste all the content in a new Texnic center file, the compilation fails

Comment: Try this document (call it e.g. `example.tex`): `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{lamport86}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}`
together with the bibliography `example.bib` containing: `@book{lamport86, author =    "Leslie Lamport", title =     "\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System", publisher = "AW", year =  "1986", address =   "Reading, MA"}` Then ask a new question saying either that this document does not work with Texnic center, or that this document works but the other not. I think that Texnic center is not setup correctly.

Comment: i think that this problem was caused by a conflict between teXnic center and tex maker. i I uninstalled them, then i downloaded Texnicentrer 2.02... know i compiled my  project with an very good speed and without error..